# What can I use to get dust off of my rMBP display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, macos

I've noticed that the Retina display on MacBook Pros gets scratches and dings very easily.  I just recently had to replace the display for a different reason, and I'd like to put on a tempered glass screen protector to prevent scratches and dings.  The problem is that I need to make sure that the screen is completely clean and dust-free before installing the screen protector, which I've found is very difficult to do.  I'm wondering if there are any products that I could buy to help get dust off of the screen?  Would something like an [electronics brush](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0050B6CYW/) or maybe even a [camera lens brush](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B004FPOVEM/) work?  Please let me know!  Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help? If it's right—be sure to hit the checkmark to accept it! If it's not—comment below it and I'll be happy to help more!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this $13 [iKlear Screen Cleaning Bundle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0023WU6OI).

It cleans dust and grime off of any modern screen (including iPhones and Macbooks) really well and I've been using it happily for the past few years. It comes with a chamois cloth and some special spray that cleans off dust very well without harming the screen (or you—it doesn't irritate skin in my experience).

[image]

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with iKlear in any way.

Comment: I agree with owlsipe! You can also use iKlear or any glasses/computer screen cleaner and microfiber cloth to clean the outside of the computer! (It makes it look like new!)

Comment: Is that $1 for the microfibre & $12 for the packaging & snake oil? ;) There's very little that a damp microfibre won't get clean, no isopropyl needed.

Comment: @NoahL Thanks :). I've even used it on a huge TV and it worked great!!

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, the snake oil works great! I'm sure just a cloth works pretty well too, but I use and love this magic stuff.

Comment: Have you actually compared it to just a damp micro, or better still one damp one dry?

Comment: @Tetsujin Just did a three-way test on my dirty screen (divided it into three parts), and I can confirm snake juice was ever so slightly better than with water and significantly better than dry (all + microfiber cloth), though the differences are too minimal to appear on camera. Still, the iKlear was fastest at removing the stuff and it looks exactly perfect. I stand by my recommendation, though water did work pretty well too :D

Comment: Sure, the isoprop is likely to be slightly faster... but no more thorough & 12 bucks more expensive... I'll stick with water ;) [& yeah, they're useless dry unless the surface is still slightly damp from the first cloth, if you use the 2-cloth method]